# IsolatedStorage best practise

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I am building my first WP8 application and I ran into a doubt.

I have to save in the IsolatedStorage some data obtained by serializing three different object.

My code for loading this data is this:

```
public static Statistics GetData()
    {
        Statistics data = new Statistics();
        try
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("stats.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Statistics));
                    data = (Statistics)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message + "\n" + e.InnerException);

        }

        return data;
    }
```

And for saving data of course is this

```
public static void SaveStats(Statistics stats)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;
            try
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("stats.xml", FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Statistics));
                        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, xmlWriterSettings))
                        {
                            serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, stats);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Salvataggio non riuscito");
            }
        }
```

This works fine, now the problem is that I have to do the same also for other two classes.

Do I have to write the same exact code again, only changing Statistics with the other class?

Or there is something way more clever to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). 
Your serialize method would look like this:

```
public static void SaveStats<T>(T obj) where T : class, new()
{
   ...
   XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
   ...
}
```

Method invoke:

```
SaveStats<Statistics>(new Statistics());
SaveStats<OtherObject>(new OtherObject());
```